# Unable to create FastPair device on Nearby Devices console

Tags: google-nearby

I'm trying to create a Fast Pair device on the nearby devices console (https://developers.google.com/nearby/devices)

When I get to the step to upload the image, there is a loading indicator that never succeeds, and the Create button is not tappable.

My hunch is that I need to request my organization to give me some specific permissions, but I don't know which ones they are. Does anyone know what it should be?

The only GCP service that I can see that seems relevant is the Nearby Message API, which is already enabled on my account.

[image: Upload error]

When I try to upload the image, I these in JS console logs:

```
Uploading image directly through the Nearby Devices API
```

And then an exception 403 forbidden, with "The caller does not have permission"